# Call function one at at time using Dispatch in the main queue

Tags: swift, dispatch

I am trying to use dispatch in swift.
The program that I want to create is as the diagram. 
The dispatch needs to run in the main queue since the methodA uses an UIAPI.

My current code is sth like this.

```
  let serialQueue = DispatchQueue.main
  var count = 0

    serialQueue.async {
        if count == 0{
            TestHelper().methodA(title: title, art: art) { (url) in
                if url != nil{
                    completion(url)
                }else{
                    count += 1
                }
            }
        }
        print(count)
        if count == 1{
            TestHelper().methodB(title: title, art: art) { (url) in
                if url != nil{
                    completion(url)
                    return
                }else{
                    count += 1
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with this code is that it does not wait for method A to finish and checks the count making methodB unexecuted.

[image]
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you heard of promise kit? You can chain functions together so they happen exactly in order, and if any fail the errors can be caught in a catch block. It would read something like this: `getSomething(title, art).then(buildUI).then(animate).done { print("Done" } .catch { error in print(error) }` Then you just make sure that the functions in the chain are on the main thread that need to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to run on the main queue you don't need a dispatch queue. All you need is a way to wait for the callback to fire and then run the next operation. This can be solved in different ways. (I'm assuming the methods run async).

1. You can nest your operations in the callback of the previous unit of work. This is easy, but quickly turns into a "pyramid of doom".
2. You can use something like Promises to chain these operations. This would be my go-to solution, but you need an external package for this.
3. You can put all these operations into a function that you call with the `count` in each completion block. This is the closest you what you wrote now:

```
func doWork(_ count: Int) {
  if count == 0 {
    TestHelper().methodA(title: title, art: art) { (url) in
        if url != nil {
            completion(url)
        } else {
            doWork(count + 1)
        }
      }
    }
  } else if count == 1 {
    TestHelper().methodB(title: title, art: art) { (url) in
        if url != nil {
            completion(url)
        } else {
            doWork(count + 1)
        }
      }
  } else if count == 3 {
    // ... etc
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Yes I have tested solution 1 and wanted a cleaner implementation. 
For number three the completion will give an error.